# Mysql select from subqueries returns empty set if one of the subqueries is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, subquery, dbi

I have an issue with selecting from my subqueries. If all of the subqueries return a value, everything is fine and a row with all the values I need is returned.

However, if one subquery is null or empty, I am returned an empty set even though the other six subqueries return a value.

Why is that? How can I get around it? I tried using 'isnull' and other hacks but it didn't work. I don't understand the design and why results would be returned as an empty set if just one of the subqueries fails. What are possible workarounds?

I tried using 'UNION' but that has it's own challenges because I ideally need one row returned so that Perl/DBI can slap the results into a HASH and I can match values returned to the column name, etc.

```
SELECT * FROM (
(select p.pesticides from pesticides p WHERE p.id=? and p.companyid=?) AS  pesticides,  
(select d.directions from directions d WHERE d.id=?) AS directions, 
( select i.intended from intended i where i.id=?) AS intended, 
(select c.chemicals from chemicals c where c.id=? and c.companyid=?) AS chemicals, 
(select a.aids from aids a where a.id=? and a.companyid=?) AS aids, 
(select ing.ingredients from ingredients ing where ing.id=? and ing.companyid=?) AS ingredients, 
(select s.solvents from solvents s WHERE s.id=? and s.companyid=?) AS solvents, 
(select aller.allergens from allergens aller where aller.id=?) AS allergens)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's returning an empty rowset when any one of the subqueries returns no rows because the set of subqueries is being treated as an intermediate table. Specifically, starting the SQL with `SELECT * FROM (` tells the compiler that the section inside the parenthesis is an intermediate table.

You can treat each subquery as a column instead (a subselect) like this:

```
create table T1(ID int, STR varchar(255));
create table T2(ID int, STR varchar(255));

insert into T1(ID, STR) values (1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'), (3, 'Three');
insert into T2(ID, STR) values (4, 'Four'), (5, 'Five'), (6, 'Six');

select 
     (select STR from T1 where ID = 1) COL1
    ,(select STR from T2 where ID = 4) COL2
;
```

That will work the same as your approach when all subqueries return a single row:

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| One | Four |

Where it differs is what happens when one or more subselects do not return a row. The column simply becomes NULL:

```
select 
     (select STR from T1 where ID = 1) COL1
    ,(select STR from T2 where ID = 8) COL2 -- ID 8 does not exist
;
```

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| One | null |

SQL Fiddle with this for MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1a209/1